# Why when printing empty string, zeros pop up?

Tags: java, android

I'm printing an empty string because I want my display to be nothing when the user clicks clear. But for some reason, it's coming up with zeros instead, any reason why?

```
display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);}

//When button is clicked, display the text. How do I do this for the rest of my variables?

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
         case R.id.bOne: display.append("1"); break;
         case R.id.bTwo: display.append("2"); break;
         case R.id.bThree: display.append("3"); break;
         case R.id.bFour: display.append("4"); break;
         case R.id.bFive: display.append("5"); break;
         case R.id.bSix: display.append("6"); break;    
         case R.id.bSeven: display.append("7"); break;
         case R.id.bEight: display.append("8"); break;
         case R.id.bNine: display.append("9"); break;
         case R.id.bZero: display.append("0"); break;
         case R.id.bPoint: display.append("."); break;
         case R.id.bClear: display.setText("");
         case R.id.bAdd: double counter = Double.toString(display);
                        //counter+=counter;
                        //display.setText(counter);
```

**Edit**

I'm programming a caclulator in Java for an Android project through Eclipse. And it's an EditTExt display.

Comment: You are going to need to add more information

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. What is display? When is this code running? Also, printing and setting the text of a control are different things.

Comment: You probably have a numeric field selected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code:

```
   case R.id.bClear:

       display.setText("");
```

you miss the break; sentence